# Calling fcsh from PHP script

Tags: php, apache-flex, fcsh

My question is whether or not Flex's fcsh can be called from within a PHP script.  Here is the background:

I have been created a simple process that creates a simple quiz/tutorial by converting a text file into a .mxml file and compiling to a .swf file using the mxmlc compiler.  This works well from the command line, but I wanted to make the process easier by creating a web-interface to do this.  My initial attempts with PHP's exec() function have not worked.  The Python scripts I use to create the .mxml file work fine (using exec()), but I have not been able to get the mxmlc compiler to work.

After searching on the Web and on this site, I believe that using fcsh (instead of mxmlc) may be the way to go.  Using fcsh would certainly compile the .mxml file faster (after the first run), and I think that fcsh can be launched as a service that might be able to be called from PHP.

On the other hand, maybe I am approaching this the wrong way.  Would it be better to write a Flex application that calls fcsh and avoid using PHP?

**Edit:** Using fcshctl as hasseg suggested in his answer below worked very well.  Thanks Ali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with calling fcsh from within scripts is that it works as an *interactive shell* instead of taking command-line arguments, compiling, and returning an exit status. There are different ways to get around this, which I've listed in [this blog post of mine](http://hasseg.org/blog/?p=194), where I mainly talk about `fcshctl` (which is my own solution for this,) but at the bottom of the post I've also listed other similar solutions to get fcsh integrated into nonstandard build workflows.

Comment: I have seen your post, and I like the idea.  I will be trying fchsctl out to see if it works.  Thanks,
Vern

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other ways in php to execute an external script.  They are exec(), passthru(), system(), and backticks i.e. the key to the left of the 1 key.  Each one has a different purpose and return mechanism.

You may have to put the command that executes your executable into a script and call that script via one of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you can't use `mxmlc` directly? It seems like it would be easier to call than `fcsh`. Just specify all your compiler options in a XML file run it like `mxmlc -load-config path/to/config.xml`. You can find an example of the XML configuration format in `FLEX_HOME/frameworks/flex-config.xml`.